# How can I troubleshoot an external flash that won’t slide all the way into to a Nikon camera?

Tags: nikon, flash, troubleshooting, hotshoe-flash

Why won’t an external flash slide all the way into a Nikon camera?

This external flash won’t work; it seems like something is blocking it from clicking in.

Comment: Did you check the hotshoe for dents and that the lock lever/thumbwheel on the flash in in the open position?

Comment: Pictures or at least model numbers would be helpful too.

Comment: Since the flash shoe is open and you can easily look into it while trying to insert the flash, I don't understand why a visual inspection won't clearly show where something is blocking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130045/how-do-i-troubleshoot-my-nikon-sb-400-accessory-flash

Comment: What specific Nikon camera model? What specific flash?